# difference between django custom login view and django custom authentication backend?

Tags: python, django

[flow chart of the login process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HEPh.png)

As shown in the diagram i want to redirect the user that has not yet created a fullname to the url('profile:profile_create').

If the user has already created a fullname then redirect to the url('profile:profile_view')

**What is the better way of handling the process? custom login view or custom authentication backend?**

authviews.py

```
class LoginView(FormView):

    success_url = settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL
    form_class = AuthenticationForm
    redirect_field_name = REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
    template_name = 'registration/login.html'

    @method_decorator(sensitive_post_parameters('password'))
    @method_decorator(csrf_protect)
    @method_decorator(never_cache)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Sets a test cookie to make sure the user has cookies enabled
        request.session.set_test_cookie()

        return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        auth_login(self.request, form.get_user())

        # If the test cookie worked, go ahead and
        # delete it since its no longer needed
        if self.request.session.test_cookie_worked():
            self.request.session.delete_test_cookie()

        return super(LoginView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        redirect_to = self.request.GET.get(self.redirect_field_name)
        if not is_safe_url(url=redirect_to, host=self.request.get_host()):
            redirect_to = self.success_url
        return redirect_to
```

**Any customization in the `get_success_url()` function leads to unsafe request** how to i solve the problem?

Comment: IMO the 1st one. Use a custom login view.

Comment: is there any referencefor the logic for the above? i am a newibe to django..

Comment: How about a google search with terms like these: `django redirect user after login` ?

Answer (score 1):

I can't think why you'd want a custom authentication backend. As the name implies, that's for when you want to change the way Django carries out authentication - which you're not doing.

The only thing that changes here is where you redirect to after logging in, which is solely the job of the login view.

Comment: is there any online reference? any basic reference for the logic?

Comment: Yes of course, there's a whole page describing how to log users in: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests

Comment: i have updated the question. Customizing the `get_success_url()` function returns unsafe request.